# Getting a mysql 2002 error only when using localhost (rather than 127.0.0.1) when connecting to mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following php file:

```
<?php
function show_error($stage) {
    echo "<p>MySql error: " . mysql_error() . '</p>';
    echo "<p>ErrorCode: " . mysql_errno() . '</p>';
    die($stage);

}

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'blog', 'sql-password');
if (!$link) {
    show_error('connect');
}
mysql_select_db('blog') or show_error();
$result = mysql_query('select col1 from test_table');
if (!$result) {
    show_error('query');
}
$col = mysql_result($result, 0);
echo "<p>Result is: [" . $col . "]</p>";
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

When I run this, I get error:

```
MySql error: No such file or directory

ErrorCode: 2002

connect
```

However, if I change the line

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'blog', 'my-password');
```

to

```
$link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'blog', 'my-password');
```

it all works correctly. How can I fix this so that it works with either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, and why does using `localhost` work differently to `127.0.0.1`?

Extra info (some google responses indicated these were important):

- the line `127.0.0.1       localhost` appears in my `/etc/hosts` file, and `ping localhost` works correctly, and hits the `127.0.0.1` address. There are no other lines mentioning `localhost` in the `/etc/hosts` file.
- I'm running it in Mac OSX Snow Leopard.
- Finally, the result of the command `stat /tmp/mysql.sock` is:

  234881044 28829652 srwxrwxrwx 1 _mysql wheel 0 0 "Jul 10 18:29:37 2011" "Jul 10 18:29:37 2011" "Jul 10 18:29:37 2011" "Jul 10 18:29:09 2011" 4096 0 0 /tmp/mysql.sock

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MySQL client magically knows that 'localhost' means the local machine, so it tries to connect to a Unix socket instead of making a network request--which is actually more efficient.  The problem here is that you're either not using a Unix socket, or--probably more likely--the MySQL client libraries don't know where to find the Unix socket file.

I wish I could tell you where that configuration lives, but a) I haven't actively used MySQL in over 3 years, and b) I've never used MySQL on OSX.

Comment: Thanks, that is the clue I needed! Since it must have been a php issue not finding the sql socket, I searched php.ini for "socket", and found the option "mysql.default_socket", which had the wrong value. Changing that to "/tmp/mysql.sock" fixed the problem.

Comment: Or you can just comment out the hardcoded mysql.sock values in php.ini and then it will use the correct defaults